# Mischief in close voting?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I'm rather new at the site and think I make some progress now and then how to use and participate. Some of my contributions are real bad, I surely admit, as for example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/950958/a-simple-set-theory, that seems to be the result of a blackout, and I really don't care if the community vote for closing that question.

But now some users want to close a reasonable question of mine with a good and accepted answer and I can't even guess any fair reason: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/953716/how-to-express-oplus-with-only-neg-and-implies.

So what is this? I really don't care if the question will be closed and deleted, since I got the answer and the question isn't very interesting, but somehow it feels that some persons vote to close with obscure motives.

Or have I missed something totally?

So it has been closed with the motivation "This question is missing context or other details" which is not true.

There are no missing context or details in the question.

But since no one will answer, apparently, I'll guess one have to live with the annoying fact that users amuses them self by closing others questions instead of ask questions of their own.

Comment: The second question seems a bit close-worthy, since if you sit to do the hard work yourself, of translating all the usual connectives to $\lnot,\rightarrow$ and then translate the statement $(p\land q)\lor\lnot(p\lor q)$ then you'll have the answer just fine. It's purely mechanical, and anyone aware that $\lnot,\rightarrow$ can represent every other connective should be able to do that on their own.

Comment: You might want to close the other question yourself if you think it is that bad.

Comment: [I direct you to this thread if you think your question should be reopened and you want to make your case.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6424/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-etc) I personally voted to close your question, because it's nothing more than a problem statement that you could as well have copied from your homework. I doubt it will be reopened. Now English isn't my first language, and maybe it isn't yours, but... "Mischief"?

Comment: (As an aside) "I really don't care if the question is closed and deleted, since I got the answer": the failings of MSE, illustrated in a single sentence.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila: never the less I didn't manage to do the job myself and similar questions are common: "express this with help of that". Usually I'm rather good at such transformations but this time I didn't succeed.

Comment: @Did: yes I know, but there are answers that aren't bad, even if I didn't understand that at the time. I don't want to delete it just because it's embarrassing.

Comment: @Najib Idrissi: it's an ordinary question and I really think that mischief is the word a looked for. It seems personally... The question isn't that bad even if I should have been able to solve it my self. No, for my own sake I don't care, if the community thinks that the question is that bad. But there is something else in this. There really are a lot of questions like this on the site - and my guess is that non of them ever has been closed.

Comment: @Lehs Are you saying you believe it's something personal? I can assure you, it's most definitely not. If you want, [here is a screenshot of my most recent close votes](http://i.imgur.com/k9hwuQf.png). If you see other questions that you feel are more worthy of being closed, flag them.

Comment: But let's be honest, your question was not good. It was just a problem statement with no input from your part, it looks like it comes straight from your homework sheet, and it was simply a matter of computing the result. I vote to close questions like that on sight, and many other users do. Some questions still manage to go through, but the fact that your question was closed isn't evidence that you're persecuted or something.

Comment: About your set-theory thing, I am no expert in this subject but I can see there is a unique answer, rather short, which ends by "which in turn would make your main question meaningless". This seems to make for an at least plausible candidate to deletion. (I might fail to understand your position on the other question as well, but this is an other can of worms so I will just add that, like @Najib, I find the use of "Mischief" rather inappropriate. And yes, a lot of crap survives on the site, so what?)

Comment: @Najib Idrissi: just press Answer and explain what context or detail that is missing in the question! And for you "did" there is surprisingly little crap on MSE. And my question is NOT crap. If I had found the entrance it would have been easy, but I didn't. And, what ever you write here, I will always know that it was a rather simple but ordinary question that didn't harm MSE at all. Some attitudes here, however, seems to be of no benefit at all.

Comment: I was only addressing your argument that "There really are a lot of questions like this on the site - and my guess is that non(e) of them ever has been closed", which, to me, and independently of what one thinks of your two questions on main, is not a convincing argument.

Comment: Well, if you don't answer me, I'll not answer you. The crap on MSE is not the questions or the answers, but some attitudes. And don't forget to vote on your comments.

Comment: I have removed the name roll. It is better to discuss the abstract general issue you describe, than the very subjective version that resulted from your last paragraph.

Comment: "Well, if you don't answer me, I'll not answer you." This might be meant to address my last comment (but I am not sure). If it is, what are the questions you asked that I should have answered but failed to? "The crap on MSE is not the questions or the answers, but some attitudes." Well, some questions are definitely crap (some answers too, I guess, but probably a lot less). "And don't forget to vote on your comments." This one does not parse, sorry.

Comment: @Did: **No, it was not meant to be an answer to you, but to those users that closed the question on faulty motives.**

Comment: Ah, OK, sorry for the noise then.

Comment: "There really are a lot of questions like this on the site - and my guess is that non of them ever has been closed." Those of us who have been here a little longer are able to see lists of closed questions. I see 45 questions that have been closed, just in the last 10 hours. Some would argue that's way too many, some would argue that's way too few, but whatever the case you should be aware there is nothing the least bit unusual about questions being closed here. It's not aimed at you.

Answer (score 5):

As someone who reviewed the Question and narrowly decided against voting to close it, perhaps I'm can give some constructive suggestions on what needs to be improved.

At the very end of the Question's first paragraph we read:

> Note: $\wedge$ is not allowed!

It's enough that you ask to express XOR in terms of NOT and IMPLIES.  This in itself is fairly easily done, which makes many Readers suspect that if you'd only give the problem a bit more thought, you would find the expression for yourself.

The subject matter is okay, but the redundant (and imperative) injunction not to use AND makes this Reader suspect that you simply don't understand the Question that you are asking.  How will you know if you get an Answer, whether it is correct or not, if you've asked something that you can't even define?  I don't know if that's the case here, but I'm saying the lack of context and "almost rude" presentation of the problem raise the suspicion.

So -- for the to-do list to Edit the Question and perhaps get it reopened, work on being less imperious and more generous with sharing what you do understand about the Question.  This is quite general advice, but it should pay dividends in motivating your Readers to respond with thoughtful Answers.

Comment: I had a bad day and though it was more difficult than it was showed to be. I will take away the note and contemplate the reactions that my activities on MSE meet.

Comment: The truth is, that I posted this question with a feeling of satisfaction, since I had posted a lot of vague questions the days before. I thought this q. was a trend break and I really wanted the answer. Of course, I'm old enough for suspecting dementia, but I'm not especially worried. I just think this behavior is typical for me and I'm used to this kind of controversies around me.